# implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation

Tags: typescript, this

I have this function:

[image]

and I'm receiving this error message from Typescript: `'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.`

[image]

Here's the function in text:

```
async function compileTemplate(templateName: any, data: any) {
    const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), "pdf/templates", `${templateName}.hbs`)
    const html = await fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8")

    Handlebars.registerHelper("if_equal", function (a, b, opts) {
        if (a == b) {
            return opts.fn(this)
        } else {
            return opts.inverse(this)
        }
    })

    return Handlebars.compile(html)(data)
}
```

Even if I pass  type the error doesn't go away:

```
return opts.fn<any>(this)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Add "this" parameter: `function (this: .., a, b, opts) {`

Comment: Does your question depend on node and handlebars?  If so you might want to tag it as such. If not you might want to [edit] your code to be a [mre] that doesn't use undeclared types or values.  Ideally we could just copy your code, paste it into our IDEs, and see the problem you're seeing without having other problems get in the way.

Comment: @kelsny that worked, thanks. That's because `this` is implicitly passed, right? Please, write an official answer and I'll confirm as right.